# Will "Ubuntu for Android" (12.04) work with the Samsung Galaxy S2?

Tags: 12.04, android, samsung, smartphone, ubuntu-for-android

I'm trying to buy a new Android phone and I own an Ubuntu 12.04 computer...

I have the choice of a Google Galaxy Nexus, Samsung Galaxy S2 and an HTC Sensation XL.

I am aware that the HTC already works with it, but I would prefer to buy the Samsung. I already have the phone hardware specifications and have checked, but I am not sure about the Samsung or the Nexus.

So which of these phones work with Ubuntu 12.04's 'Ubuntu for Android' feature?

Comment: are you asking if you can install "Ubuntu for Android" on your phone or if your phone is compatible with Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you expand this answer to include more information and/or links? Also, the [Motorola Atrix 4G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_Atrix) runs [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)). Both Android and Ubuntu are Linux-based operating systems, but Android is not Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu-phone OS that will be available 2014?

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned on the [Ubuntu for Android page](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android), the product is marketed towards handset manufacturers rather than end users.  It is intended to be integrated into the firmware rather than act as an after market addition to existing phones.

None of the phones you've listed include the code in their firmware, and I don't think any have yet been released.

Answer (score 0):

You probably saw people run Ubuntu as a chroot or something, not the same thing.

I would bet that if Ubuntu for Android ever gets released ports will be attempted to each of those phones by modders. The reason being that the code will be **entirely** free. The troublesome non-free graphics or camera drivers required by Android 4+ have more or less been available in Android 4 upgrades. Of course you would have to allow yourself to run as root first. The only problem, could be optimizing it for all these dual-core CPUs. In that list I think there are *four* different manufacturers involved, there are regional variants of the s2.

If you are serious about modding, the GN is made for that with an "open" chip architecture and simple boot-loader unlocking. Though, that said, there are a lot of modders for the s2 not so much the XL.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, Canonical will be working towards compatibility for all smartphones with quad-core processors according to the official [Ubuntu for Android Page](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android). If the Samsung Galaxy S2 has a processor like this, it will probably happen. But maybe just not as quickly as the others! So, you may have to wait in return for wanting it on such a phone, but there is no doubt that Ubuntu will work towards it.

You can also install Ubuntu on some devices. See [here](http://ubuntudan.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/how-to-run-ubuntu-on-samsung-galaxy-s2.html) for more info.